# Add empty td to rows which have less tds than max

Tags: javascript, html-table

I dynamically add data to table from a Javascript object.
I have a code that ends up something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want table borders in each row even if the tds don't exist. So basically for the example in the code I want a 3x3 table with borders.
Is this possible without actually making empty tds in each row?

Comment: please show the code you are using to get this output

Comment: it's really a lot of code.It's an object, which is then sorted by numbers, and then each item is split by a dot and the TD's are built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- Modify the original JS so that it generates `colspan` attributes (`<td colspan="3">` will be as wide as 3 `<td>`'s; Of course you will lose the grid symmetry.
- If your table cells each have the same fixed width, you could use a background-image on the table.
- You could wrap up [a little script](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/frysj6cb/) to complete the table, cf:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
function normalizeTable() {
    var trs = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'), 
        len = trs.length, max = 0, td;
    // first we search for the longest table row in terms of # of children 
    for (var i = len; i--;) {
        if (trs[i].children.length > max) 
            max = trs[i].children.length;
    }
    // now we can fill the other rows
    for (var j = len; j--;) {
        while (trs[j].children.length < max) {
            td = document.createElement('td');
            trs[j].appendChild(td);
        }
    }
}
normalizeTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

In my opinion, you have to add only a little CSS and insert all TD (empty):

```css
table {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    empty-cells: show;
}

td {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>  <!-- empty -->
    <td></td>  <!-- empty -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>  <!-- empty -->
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: but when I build the first row, I don't know yet that there are 3 columns in row 2.Do i Have to go through the data once to get the max number, and then the second time to build the table?

Comment: Right! My idea is add, in each rows, the max number of TDs. Starting from a TABLE of 1 x 1. I know that your question is a little different.